# Mongodb crashed with Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault)

Tags: mongodb

My mongo server crashed with the following log. My mongo server is of version 2.4.2 and my mongo java client is 2.11.2. My environment is RHEL

Please let know as to what could eb the problem.. I see from other threads that the older version before 2.2.x had this problem, but mine is 2.4.2. Any help..

```
...
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.924 [conn78956] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.924 [conn78956] command admin.$cmd command: { ismaster: 1 }        ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:263 0ms
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.938 [conn78962] runQuery called admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.938 [conn78962] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.938 [conn78962] command admin.$cmd command: { ismaster: 1 }     ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:263 0ms
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.938 [conn78965] runQuery called admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.938 [conn78965] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.938 [conn78965] command admin.$cmd command: { ismaster: 1 }   ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:263 0ms
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.938 [conn78964] runQuery called admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.938 [conn78964] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.938 [conn78964] command admin.$cmd command: { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:263 0ms
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.941 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member 204.27.36.236:5000 is up
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.941 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member 204.27.36.236:5000 is now in state SECONDARY
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.941 [rsMgr] replSet warning caught unexpected exception in electSelf()
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.941 Invalid access at address: 0 from thread: 

Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.941 Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).

Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.941 [conn78959] runQuery called admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.941 [conn78959] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.941 [conn78959] command admin.$cmd command: { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:263 0ms
Thu Feb 20 13:45:56.943 Backtrace:
0xdced21 0x6cf749 0x6cfcd2 0x30e160f4c0 
/home/myserver/mySer/db/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdced21]
/home/myserver/mySer/db/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x399) [0x6cf749]
/home/myserver/mySer/db/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo24abruptQuitWithAddrSignalEiP7siginfoPv+0x262) [0x6cfcd2]
 /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x30e160f4c0]
```